# Virtualmin FTP/SFTP connection and large files

Tags: ftp, sftp

I have added FTP user to an account and assigned to that user shell /bin/sh so can connect using SFTP. I have tested connection with a small file but it comes that can't upload anything bigger than 0.5GB.

I have tried to connect with root privileges and use SFTP to upload larger file (0.8GB) and I'm getting disconnected often with an error "Optimize connection buffer size"

/var/log/messages looks like:

```
Sep 17 09:55:11 server06 proftpd[30911]: 10.38.30.20 (::ffff:96.233.206.91[::ffff:96.233.206.91]) - Client session idle timeout, disconnected 

Sep 17 09:55:11 server06 proftpd[30911]: 10.38.30.20 (::ffff:96.233.206.91[::ffff:96.233.206.91]) - FTP session closed. 

Sep 17 09:55:22 server06 proftpd[31432]: 10.38.30.20 (::ffff:96.233.206.91[::ffff:96.233.206.91]) - notice: user xyz.aabbcc: aborting transfer: Input/output error
```

Any clue what is going on with both issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the logs you can see the the session is timing out.

That's why your transfer gets aborted.

Increase the timeout value.

Comment: Increase timeout value on the ftp server or ftp client software?

Comment: On the server. Probably you are going over SSH there (since you mentioned SFTP/shell account - just a guess).